# Does spark support accessing RDD's across drivers

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Let's say i created an RDD using RSpark, can i access that RDD using pyspark driver ? Does spark support accessing RDD's across drivers ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it does not.  You can store your RDD in HDFS and share it that way.  If you want to store it in memory you can use Tachyon to store it.